# How can I add publish message configuration on a running IBusControl

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with RabbitMqTransport. 
Assume I have run `IBusControl` using:

```cs
var control = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
{
    var host = confgurator.Host(config.BuildHostUri(), h =>
    {
    ...
    });
...
});

await control.StartAsync();
```

Later I connected new endpoint to this running instance, using:

```cs
host.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(Configuration.QueueName, this.ConfigureEndpoint);
```

Is there a way to configure Publish/Send for new Message types at this moment also? By "configure Publish/Send" I mean using methods like existing on `IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator`:

```cs
confgurator.Send<MessageContract>(_ =>
{
    _.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(__ => Configuration.QueueName);
});
confgurator.Message<MessageContract>(x => x.SetEntityName(nameof(MessageContract)));
confgurator.Publish<MessageContract>(_ =>
{
...
}
```

Comment: The configureEndpoint method you're passing should have access to the same publish/send configurators that the bus factory configurator has access.

Comment: `ConfigureEndpoint` callback only have `IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator`, there is no publish/send configurators in it (or I didn't find them)

Comment: The pipe specifications are there, the topology configuration isn't there. I'm pretty sure the reason being that this stuff should be configured up front, if the bus publishes a 'MessageContract' it would need to have the same topology configured and doing it only for a receive endpoint would create confusion.

Comment: I guess you right. So my question is still, can I add new Publish/Send Message configuration to a running IBusControl (not through `ConnectReceiveEndpoint`)? Or this kind of configuration can only be done on IBusControl startup?

Comment: Only during configuration, prior to starting the bus.

Answer (score 1):

As per Chris Patterson comment, configuring Publish/Send for message type can only be done during configuration, prior to starting the bus.